# Iphone & iPad - how to exclude a resource from a target?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

I have two targets on my project - iPad and iPhone. Some resources, as interface images, are exclusively for iPad and others for iPhone.

How do I exclude an image, for example, of being included on a given target.

This project of mine was created using that "transition" stuff and groups were created: Resources-iPad and Resources-iPhone. I have organized each resource inside one of these groups. Even so, every final product has both resources.

Am I missing something? thanks for any help.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314050/when-compiling-for-multiple-targets-in-xcode-how-do-i-ensure-that-certain-files

Comment: two waves on the shore appear the same but they are not. Even if it is a duplicate, an answer may succeed to explain something better than another. Diversity is what makes it interesting.

Comment: The philosophy of this site is that there be only one question for a given topic, so that users do not have to read multiple questions to get all possible answers: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the "copy resources" step for the target in question and delete any resources you don't want in there. In addition, you should right-click the resource, select "Get Info" and remove it from any targets you don't want using the Targets tab.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on a resource file, select Get Info, open the Targets tab and click checkboxes as needed.