# Customizing File Linkage for a Build Configuration (Not Buil Target)

Tags: iphone, xcode, build-process

I have a project that has several build configurations (FREE version, male-only, female-only, etc.).  I am avoiding using multiple build targets because (A) the products are mostly all the same and (B) I don't want to have to do checkbox-management to keep every file I have included with all the targets.

However, I have just a few files it would be nice NOT to include in certain builds.  For example, I have male and female voice files, but I only want the male files in the male build and female voices in the female build.

Question...is there a way to manage the build configuration to prevent these files from being included/linked in?  What are my options?

Comment: This question asks something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314050/when-compiling-for-multiple-targets-in-xcode-how-do-i-ensure-that-certain-files , if you were willing to go the different target route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use multiple targets with different copy files build phases. However, if you really want to make it harder on yourself, you could write a shell script which will remove the unwanted files from the product before code signing and set up a new shell script phase in your build process.

Usually, duplicating your existing target and removing unwanted files there is the easiest choice though.