# How to tell Xcode 5 not to include certain resources in certain targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have a paid and a free version of an app. In the free version, a lot of images need to be excluded.

I [duplicated the target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314050/when-compiling-for-multiple-targets-in-xcode-how-do-i-ensure-that-certain-files) and called it Free Version. Then I selected the images in Project Navigator that should not go into the free version and toggled their target membership off for Free Version.

However Xcode 5 seems to completely ignore the target membership and keeps including all resources into the free version. How can I tell Xcode not do do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove needed resource from Copy Bundle Resources section.

(YourProject->NeededTarget->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So the Target Membership setting is irrelevant? Or do you have to keep an eye both on Target Membership and Copy Bundle Resources list and sync it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have duplicated the project file and you don't want the images file to be added. You could just select those image files and press delete button and give remove references. This will ensure that the files are accessible by the paid version.